# Book about a modern day woman who was reliving a previous life or lives in which she was a witch

Tags: story-identification, books, reincarnation, witches

I read this book in the mid 2000’s (likely 2015-ish), though I don’t know that it was a new book at the time.

I *think* it was a modern day woman who was reliving a previous life or lives in which she was a witch.

There were definitely raunchy moments, so not a young persons' book.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art?  What format was it?  (e-book, hardcover, paperback...)

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example; What was her name? What was the setting? What was her job in the modern world? Did she have a partner? What kind of witch was she? When was she a witch? How was she 'reliving' her previous life?